# Arm template deployment failed

Tags: azure-rm-template, azure-hybrid-connections

I tried to automate to manage hybrid connections in azure through deployment of arm template through storage blobs . The problems comes when it asks for key and value which is entered in user metadata property .The template is deployed successfully but when I try to open the properties page of Hybrid connection it shows an error whose image is being shared.
I am also sharing some part of the arm template which shows how I define user metadata.

I have tried changing the syntax of the user metadata property in the json file but that doesn't help.

```
    {
          "name": "[concat(parameters('servicebus_name'), 
    '/hybridConnectionName')]",
          "type": "Microsoft.Relay/namespaces/hybridConnections",
          "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
          "location": "East US",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Relay/namespaces', 
    parameters('servicebus_name'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "requiresClientAuthorization": true,
            "userMetadata": "\" 
    [concat('[{\\\"key\\\":\\\"endpoint\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"', 
    variables('myEndpoint'), '\\\"}]')]\" "
            ]
          }
        }
```

The error message is displayed on the properties page of Hybrid connections and it shows :
Part's onInputsSet promise failed.(id: Microsoft_Azure_Relay-fx-010-00e)

Comment: Check if this helps https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/301-azure-relay-create-authrule-namespace-and-hybridconnection/azuredeploy.json